# How can I get my LAN IP address using Java

Tags: java, server, inetaddress

I want to get my LAN IP address. But I it shows Localhost address using this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
    InetAddress add=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Local IP: " + add.getHostAddress());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}        
}
```

It shows IP is : 127.0.1.1 . 
But my LAN ip address is 10.107.46.88

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what the result of the code listed actually is and why that's not useful. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: you want to retrieve your public ip address, not the local ip

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I know is to use [`NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces--) and the linked Javadoc notes that you *can use `getNetworkInterfaces()`+`getInetAddresses()` to obtain all IP addresses for this node*. That might look something like

```
try {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nics = NetworkInterface
            .getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (nics.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface nic = nics.nextElement();
        Enumeration<InetAddress> addrs = nic.getInetAddresses();
        while (addrs.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress addr = addrs.nextElement();
            System.out.printf("%s %s%n", nic.getName(),
                    addr.getHostAddress());
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and I get (for my network)

```
wlan0 192.168.2.9
lo 127.0.0.1
```

if you don't want to display loop-back you can test the `NetworkInterface` with [`isLoopback()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#isLoopback--).

```
while (nics.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface nic = nics.nextElement();
    if (!nic.isLoopback()) {
        // ... as before
    }
}
```

Comment: Really its very helpful. But I want to get only LAN IP address.

Comment: @Uzzal That's what he's given you.